# Primary Foreign Key slowing down InnoDB inserts

Tags: mysql

I'm importing a lot (only ~10,000) of employees and then making them all a user account at once. Inserting into my user_profile table is slowing everything down a ton because the primary key of the table is a foreign key as well, and not the usual autoincrement id.

Is there any way to speed this up? 
Or do I need to go back and add an autoincrement id to user_profile somehow?

Edit:

```
user:
  id
  username
  salt
  password

user_profile:
  user_id -> Primary Key and Foreign Key to user table
  first_name
  last_name
  email
  ...
```

Comment: "primary key of the table is a foreign key as well, and not the usual autoincrement id" huh? Can you post the schema?

Comment: A schema would be helpful. You could always drop the constraint and re-add it as a last resort.

Comment: I'm using this plugin: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin

And following this post's advice for creating a 1-1 relationship for the Propel ORM.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715164/relation-one-to-one-in-sf1-4-propel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to add a `id` field to the `user_profile` table, make it the primary key (unsigned and auto_increment). Then make the `user_id` field the foreign key to the user (`id`) table. I've never seen a field act as the primary key AND foreign key to another table.